Xdebug seems to be starting and stops without doing anything, even tho I set up the breakpoints
I have been encountering following problem:
I have a server that runs my PHP applications. It is in the same network as my local machine. The address of the server is 192.168.0.21.
I want to debug the scripts on this server in my local IDE. So:

I made a SSH connection to edit files directly on the server.
Installed the Xdebug extension on my IDE (Visual Studio Code)
Installed Xdebug on the server and checked the phpinfo() - it sees Xdebug.

Back then I wasn't able to connect to the local machine from the server on the port 9003 so I changed it and telnet shows that my connection to local machine is successful.
It doesn't stop at breakpoints, it doesn't do anything actually. Am I missing something?

I have tried to restart Apache multiple times, I have tried to set local path mapping (which don't make sense to me, but saw it on the other website), disabled firewall
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 7680,
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}

[207613] Log opened at 2024-06-17 08:39:12.333867
[207613] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.0.138:7680.
[207613] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.0.138:7680 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[207613] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14" protocol_version=>

[207613] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=192.168.0.138
xdebug.client_port=7680
xdebug.log = /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level=7


"Am I missing something?" That's possible. 1) What's 7680 -- what service is running on that port? 2) fileuri="dbgp://stdin" -- I do not like it. It normally should have a file and not stdin there....

@LazyOne seems like svchost.exe is running on this port. I have changed the port from 9003 becouseit refused to connect on that port :/

xdebug.client_port is for Xdebug client (quoting you -- "Xdebug extension on my IDE (Visual Studio Code)") So the process should be Code.exe (in netstat -abn output the process is written below the matching entry, not above -- you may have red it wrong). Anyway: change both to 9003 (or 9004 if you so like) and try again. Based on the Xdebug log you have posted, the response is: go away. Whatever service responded is aware of the protocol used by Xdebug. And the response basically tells that it has nothing to debug (for whatever reason). Enable logs from VSCode as well

Well, now it seems like nothing is listening on 9003. I changed the ini file on the server and launch,json, restarted apache, IDE and whole local machine and nothing helped. I lsted all listening processes on the windows machine and 9003 is gone here.

That's odd then: try next port (IDE side first, until see it listed in netstat or similar app output). What about actual Windows Firewall -- maybe it's accidentally blocked there? Regardless -- when changing ports go higher numbers, not lower. If the IDE is unable to listen on that port, it should show an error (the expected behaviour).

Sorry if i'm asking dumb questions - IDE should show me that it cant listen on the port specified in the launch.json once I would run the debugging session?
Do new logs could tell something about current tries ( i have tried multiple ports > 9003)
[Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.0.138:9003.
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '192.168.0.138:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.0.138:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

When you click on Run icon for "Listen for Xdebug" configuration, the Xdebug extension of your VSCode should be listening on that port (so you should see it in the netstat output). If you try to use a port that is already used by another process (on the same IP/network interface, normally it should be 0.0.0.0 which means ALL), you would see an error message (e.g. try using 80 there which is used by a web server etc) -- "Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80"

But that's on VSCode side of things. The log you have shown is from Xdebug side (which is another server). It cannot tell why connection cannot be established: it could be nobody is listening on that IP:port pair, could be firewall blocking, could be wrong IP... So my suggestion is: use that "Listen for Xdebug" configuration and make sure that VSCode is listening first.

netstat -na | findstr ":9003" in PowerShell (with admin rights) to see all entries where that port is present (will filter out process names though, as it is shown on a separate line). But this would be enough to see if something is listening on the target port or not. P.S. if 9003 etc does not work -- go back to 7680 or whatever. Just make sure it's VSCode that uses it.

I had port 9003 listening but I noticed, that once I run the Listen for Xdebug configuration it also did the port forwarding automatically, for the port 9003. Is that right? From my point of view there should not be any port forwarding, just code.exe listening on 9003. Am I right?
Im gonna check on the other machine if I'll got any problems with that and will update here

Port forwarding? Nope. Never used it myself in VSCode. You must have set it up by mistake or for something else. "From my point of view there should not be any port forwarding, just code.exe listening on 9003. Am I right?" Yes. Plus, I'm not familiar with what exactly that does in VSCode.

If you have managed to resolve your issue, then please share your solution as an answer -- it will be helpful to other users in a similar situation.

The issue was with my visual studio code configuration. I dont know what exactly went wrong, but I have managed to set up debugger on the other devices. It still refused to listen on picked port in launch.json file and once it was not listening on that port, xdebug was closing connection in a second. Now resintalled the VS with removing all C:/AppData/Roaming/Code files and works like a charm!
@LazyOne very much thanks for your help!

Post is as an answer then -- it will help others. It's unlikely that someone will read comments just to se ethe last one. A question with an accepted answer has much better visibility. It might have been your "port forwarding" in VSCode (never used it myself).

@LazyOne one more thing. I managed to set up the debugger but with the folder mapping:
"pathMappings":{
"/var/www/html/myapp": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
in my launch.json. Is it possible, to access the remote machine and edit the files directly, so setting up the breakpoints directly on the server, without folder mapping? Idk if that makes sense, but to be honest it was my original goal.
Once I was trying to use remote development plugin it again refused to listen on 9003 - causing debugger not run again.

I'm PhpStorm user. Used VSCode just to see how it works / some other file edits (like PowerShell scripts, Markdown & Python files mainly). Even if I would use VSCode for PHP -- for me it's all local. I mean -- I have a local copy of a website so I will have to use path mappings. Never tried to do Full Remote (be it VSCode or PhpStorm).

Anyway, thank you for your help once again!

The issue was with my visual studio code configuration. I dont know what exactly went wrong, but I have managed to set up debugger on the other devices. It still refused to listen on picked port in launch.json file and once it was not listening on that port, xdebug was closing connection in a second. Now resintalled the VS with removing all C:/AppData/Roaming/Code files and works like a charm!
